# How to enable port 21 with vsftpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I can connect to my ftp server with port 22.
but I think port 21 is not active.:

> Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
> Error:    Could not connect to server

ufw status

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

my vsftpd.config:

```
listen=YES

listen_ipv6=YES

local_enable=YES
write_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
user_sub_token=$USER local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
pasv_min_port=40000 pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist userlist_deny=NO
```

#netstat -lntu

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
```

output of netstat:

```
#netstat -pant | grep 21

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      299540/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 ****:22       *****:52150    ESTABLISHED 299854/sshd: unknow
```

status of vsftpd:

```
# systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-30 13:27:34 UTC; 53s ago
    Process: 299078 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 299082 (vsftpd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4575)
     Memory: 916.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
             └─299082 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Comment: Is `vsftpd` running? What is it's status?

Comment: @Kahn added my status.

Comment: Out of curiosity, yhy do you care about ssh port 22?

Comment: What command or tool are you using on the client to connect to this service? Why do you think that port 21 (ftp/tcp) isn't active?

Comment: You probably cannot connect to your FTP server on port 22 - it's much more likely that you are connecting to your ssh/sftp/scp server. Even if the same daemon may be capable of providing an STP service (but from the data you provided it is not) this is still not an FTP server on port 22. And, BTW, its 2023 - there is no good reason for still using FTP.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called **listen_port** you can set it in your vsftpd.config file like:

```
listen_port=21
```